# Translate data right in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, query, query-layer, calculate-values

I have a point feature layer in ArcGIS Online.

I want to create a query on top of that FC that will translate the data:

1. Calculate and concatenate fields
2. Use coded value domain descriptions instead of codes

---

Reason:

I want to integrate the points to an external system on a nightly schedule (the external system makes an HTTP call to ArcGIS Online). I'll need to translate the data so that it is in a format that can be imported into the the external system's table.

In a typical integration setup, the data translation would happen on the external system side. But the external system has limited functionality. So I want to determine what my translation/query options are on the ArcGIS Online side -- to see if ArcGIS Online can help format the data beforehand.

---

Question:

Are there there any mechanisms in ArcGIS Online that can automatically query/translate data? (without the need to import into ArcGIS Enterprise as an intermediary step)

Comment: Have you checked out the API for developers? I suggest Python, but there are other languages. https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/features-module/

Comment: when you say "FC" do you mean feature layer? Based on your answer below, I assume so. Just wanted to clarify.  https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/feature-layers.htm

Comment: https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/working-with-feature-layers-and-features/
This doc has some examples on querying feature layers using the arcgis python api

Answer (score 0):

For #2 - *Use coded value domain descriptions instead of codes*:

I think it's possible to create a dynamic join to a table in ArcGIS Online:

> [Join Features](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/analyze/join-features.htm)
>
> Create results as hosted feature layer view allows the data to stay **up
> to date as the source data changes**. Hosted feature layer views
> containing joins will be read-only and do not consume credits for
> analysis and storage.

If that's the case, then I think I could manually create a related table that stores the domain descriptions in it. And join from the main FC to the table to get the domain descriptions.

Then, consume the feature layer in my integration.

The main downside would be: I'd need to store the domain descriptions in two places.

- The FC domain
- And the static table

But it might be an ok option as a last resort.